# Class with no name, constructor, destructor

Tags: c++

I've read about class with no name...

Got that

```
class
{ 
  int i;
};
```

is not valied while

```
class
{ 
  int i;
}A;
```

is valid.
But how to have a: 1) constructor and :2) destructor and: 3) how to pass as an argument???

Comment: You can't have a constructor or destructor. You can get the type with `decltype(A)` to use as a parameter, but then you might as well give the class a name.

Comment: If the anonymous class meets the requirement, you can still use brace initialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the class is unnamed then it can't have a custom constructor/destructor (although the compiler will generate the usual default ones for you). That means you can't pass an argument to it at construction. However, there's probably nothing stopping you from either (1) adding one or methods to the class to pass data to it after construction, or (2) giving the class a name in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You are doomed using the class locally and accessing it through the local object A, only.

You can use it in a template, though:

```
template <typename T>
inline void print(const T& a) {
    std::cout << a.x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    class {
        public: int x;
    } a;
    a.x = 1;
    print(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second thing is valid, but you cannot access the member **i** since it will be private. It is valid only because You have created an object A of that class type.

To have a constructor, *I think* you have to give the class a name. Use this:

```
class myclass
{ 
  int i;
  public:
     myclass(int a) //This is the constructor
     {
           i = a;
     }
     ~myclass()  //This is the destructor
     {
           //Whatever you want to do on destroying the object
     }

};
```

and instantiate that class as follows:

```
myclass A(10);
```

or similarly.

**Note**: This is just *my interpretation*, it can be done in many other ways.

Comment: 3.cpp:8:3: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
  noname(int a)
  ^~~~~~
3.cpp:12:4: error: expected the class name after '~' to name a destructor
  ~noname()
   ^
3.cpp:19:2: error: unknown type name 'noname'
 noname classA(10);
 ^
3 errors generated.

Comment: When declaring the class, don't instantiate with A there. Instantiate separately the way I told you.

Comment: It makes no difference if you define the variable `A` separately or not. And calling something `noname` is confusing, because `noname` is a name.

Comment: that was just my poor attempt of a pun to give the class a name :) . I will make it more obvious to everyone through my edit.